# Reason why mongoose find with limit doesn't work (express, nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection with 4000 documents.
I am trying to have an endpoint that can take a parameter as limit and this will be the amount of documents the client receives.

I would like that in the case that this limit parameter is not included, it will automatically return 3500 documents.

This is the code of the GET call:

```
app.get('/items', (req, res, next) => {
    const limit = req.query.limit || 3500;
    topItemModel.find({})
       .sort("-someSortingKey")
      .limit(limit)
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data));
      }).catch((err) => next(err));
  });
```

What happpens is that if I am not specifing limit, I will get 3500 documents, like I wanted. 
When I do call the endpoint like so

server.com/items/?limit=100

or like so:

server.com/items?limit=100

Postman shows an internal server error

What did I miss here?

Comment: Do you have any more information about the internal server error? What is the error message?

Comment: I think limit needs to be a number as it's still a string.

Comment: Yep,
.limit(parseInt(limit))
Did the trick, thanks.

Comment: If any error comes you are not returning any response. It could be the reason for internal server error, return the error in response and check.